# Code to update excel rows, is working in eclipse but not working in JSR223 PreProcessor/Sampler. No error is appearing and file is not updating

Tags: java, jmeter

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("${filePath}"));

            //HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println("Sheet -- "+sheet);

            Date date= new Date(0);

            long time = date.getTime();


            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
            for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                System.out.println("Row --- "+row);
                row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Order"+new Date().getDate()+"_"+System.nanoTime());
            }

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("${filePath}"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not doing anything because it's not being called at all. [JMeter's JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) don't automatically execute [Java main method](https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method), you will need to explicitly call it by adding the next line to the end of your script:

```
ExcelExample.main()
```

Full code just in case:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

import java.sql.Timestamp

public class ExcelExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("${filePath}"));

            //HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println("Sheet -- " + sheet);

            Date date = new Date(0);

            long time = date.getTime();


            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                System.out.println("Row --- " + row);
                row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Order" + new Date().getDate() + "_" + System.nanoTime());
            }

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("${filePath}"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

ExcelExample.main()
```

Another option is to remove Java class/method declarations like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

import java.sql.Timestamp

try {

    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("${filePath}"));

    //HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    System.out.println("Sheet -- " + sheet);

    Date date = new Date(0);

    long time = date.getTime();


    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
        System.out.println("Row --- " + row);
        row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Order" + new Date().getDate() + "_" + System.nanoTime());
    }

    file.close();

    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("${filePath}"));
    workbook.write(outFile);
    outFile.close();


} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried both ways getting below error in logs.
2019-07-01 17:57:14,327 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSF . . . '' Encountered "import" at line 2, column 1.
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSF . . . '' at line number 2
javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: ``import

Comment: I'm not enough telepathic to tell you how to solve the error without seeing its details, my expectation is that you need to have [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath), check out [How to Implement Data Driven Testing in your JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-implement-data-driven-testing-in-your-jmeter-test/) article for comprehensive instructions

Comment: Thanks . Solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by adding the below code in JSR223 Sampler.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try {

FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("${filePath}"));

            //HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            System.out.println("Sheet -- "+sheet);

            Date date= new Date(0);

            long time = date.getTime();


            Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
            for(int i=1;i<=100;i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
               System.out.println('Row --- '+row);
               def ordStr = "${__time(ddMMyyyymmss,)}_${__Random(1,100)}";
               int threadId = ${__eval(${__threadNum})};
               row.getCell(0).setCellValue("Order"+"_"+threadId+"_"+new Date().getDate()+"_"+System.nanoTime());

            }

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile =new FileOutputStream(new File("${filePath}"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
ExcelExample.main()
```